# Query to get rows with two consecutive zeros in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a data set:

```
sid  name     sub     marks  subid
11    kittu   eng     55     1
11    kittu   math    0      2
11    kittu   sci     0      3
12   bunnu    eng    0        1
12   bannu    math    44      2
12    bannu   sci     0       3
13    siva    eng     0       1
13    siva    math    0        2
13    siva   sci      88       3
```

and I want to get output like this (which have consecutive zero marks):

```
11 kittu 
13  siva
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT a row from T WHERE exists a row another with same sid and a lower subid sequentially and both rows have zero marks.
Then Do a DISTINCT just in case there are more than qualifying condition so you don't get duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sid,name
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T T2 
              WHERE T2.marks = 0 
              AND t.marks = 0
              AND T2.sid = T.sid
              AND T2.subid = t.subid + 1)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7a06e/3)