# Find Consecutive 0s SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
User    Day    Usage
User1   1      9
User1   2      11
User1   3      0
User1   4      0
User1   5      0
User1   6      0
User1   7      0
User2   1      20
User2   2      0
User2   3      0
User2   4      0
User2   5      0
User2   6      0
User2   7      13
User2   8      11
```

I want to find the user ids where usage is 0 for 5 consecutive days and also the day when it started.

In the above case, the answer should be

```
User    Day
User1   3
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611294/query-to-get-rows-with-two-consecutive-zeros-in-a-column

Comment: Not completely.

Comment: User2 on Day 2 should also be a match if I read the data correctly.

Comment: User2 Day2 wouldn't be a match as user2 has a non zero usage from Day7

Comment: Your question doesn't quite match your actual requirement, which is that usage is 0 for at least the last 5 consecutive days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `SUM` as an analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(Usage) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Day ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) UsageSum5Days,
              SUM(Usage) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Day ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) UsageSumTotal,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Day ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT User, Day, Usage
FROM cte
WHERE UsageSum5Days = 0 AND UsageSumTotal = 0 AND cnt >= 5;
```

### Demo

Comment: this would also give me rows that have user2 but user2 shouldn't be included.

Comment: @SamM I fixed it, sorry.  Tricky question.

Comment: This script still gives user2. Am I missing out on anything? Is there a a way that we can write without using "ROWS BETWEEN"?

Comment: User2 from days 2 to 6 had all zero.  There should be a User2 record in the output.  If not, then please explain the logic here.

Comment: User2 Day2 wouldn't be a match as user2 has a non zero usage from Day7

Comment: Is there a way we can write without using "ROWS BETWEEN"?

Comment: Not that comes to mind.  I mean, this is how we define the 5 day window which you want.  The default window behaviors are not for a 5 record window.

Comment: Check the @Squirrel answer to see if that's really your requirement.  It's much simpler (though perhaps not exactly what you asked for).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you wanted user with `last` `5 days` with `Usage = 0`

```
WITH cte 
AS 
(
    SELECT *, rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Day] DESC)
    FROM   yourTable
)

SELECT [User], min([Day]) as [Day]
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn <= 5
GROUP BY [User]
HAVING MIN(Usage) = 0
AND    MAX(Usage) = 0
```

Comment: This works too but I doubt this might not handle the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is `lead()`.  If you mean 5 rows ordered by the `day` column which does not have gaps, then:

```
select t.userid, t.day
from (select t.*,
             lead(day, 4) over (partition by userid, usage order by day) as lead_day4_usage
      from t
     ) t
where lead_day4_usage = day + 4 and usage = 0;
```

If there can can be gaps, then:

```
select t.userid, t.day
from (select t.*,
             lead(day, 4) over (partition by userid, usage order by day) as next_day4_usage,
             lead(day, 4) over (partition by userid order by day) as next_day4
      from t
     ) t
where next_day4_usage = next_day4 and usage = 0;
```

Note that in either of these cases you might want `select distinct` if a user can meet the conditions more than once.

Comment: This still gives me User2 in the result. So, this is not the correct answer as User2 should not be in the output table.

Comment: @SamM . . . I'm totally baffled.  Your question says "I want to find the user ids where usage is 0 for 5 consecutive days".  User2 meets that condition.